# What do you call a person who is utterly independent and a loner?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I was just in the midst of writing a description for a story I am writing, and I'm trying to describe one of the characters, or more rather think of a word I could use to describe them.

They are independent, they do everything by themselves, they enjoy solitude, and believe that friends or socialization is unnecessary and causes nothing but issues. They are quite egotistical and quite narcissistic because of this, but I'm looking for a word that explains their need to do everything alone.

If this helps, my sentence is as follows, or something along those lines:

> Marina is a proud _____, she believes that buddies are for weak people, and she could very well cope on her own.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52921/discussion-on-question-by-gigiistrash-what-do-you-call-a-person-who-is-utterly-i).

Answer (score 61):

You might call her a [***lone wolf***](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/lone%20wolf):

> a person who avoids the company or assistance of others
>   <sub>from *[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/lone%20wolf)*</sub>

The linked site goes on to explain:

> If you prefer to do things on your own, including taking care of problems and working on projects, you can call yourself a lone wolf, or a person who prefers being alone.

Comment: note: the sentence would be something like "Marina is a lone wolf", it would not be normal to say "a proud lone wolf"

Comment: @Jordan.J.D You might also write "Marina is proud to be a lone wolf."

Comment: If the OP would consider changing the notion of "proud" to that of "confirmed," a "dyed-in-the-wool lone wolf" might create an interesting image. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @PapaPoule That would be a very literal wolf in sheep’s clothing! (Dyed-in-the-lone-wolf-in-sheep’s-clothing?)

Comment: I have always preferred "lone cat" or variants thereof for OP's actual meaning... cats are actually pretty happy to be solitary, while wolves are pack animals and an actual lone wolf is probably in trouble.  It amuses me a bit because popularity of the "lone wolf" motif notwithstanding, most people are actually looking for groups, howsoever small, to fit with, making lone wolf the right term for them after all :)

Comment: @Megha Well, I would guess, that's precisely why it is "lone wolf": A "lone cat" is not that remarkable, but a "lone wolf" (like a "lone human", both are social animals) is.

Comment: +1 to this, but it should be noted that the term is _very_ cliché.

Answer (score 43):

At first I was thinking *hermit*, but settled on ***Individualist***

Google result:
in·di·vid·u·al·ist
ˌindəˈvij(ə)wələst,ˌindəˈvijələst/ noun

> 1. a person who is independent and self-reliant.
>      "a rugged individualist driven to succeed"
>       a self-centered or egotistical person.
>       "selfish individualists thinking only of themselves"
>
>    2. an advocate of a social theory favoring freedom of action for individuals over collective or state control.
>         "radical individualists, committed to quality of life"

Comment: I can see individualist best used in the context of the example sentence.  Usually proud and individualist are terms that often go together.  People see individualism as a choice.

Comment: I too like hermit for her description, but contextually, the character doesn't sound as extreme as a hermit.

Comment: "Individualist" was actually the word I was trying to think of! (I had a word on the tip of my tongue but I couldn't think of it). I really love "hermit", it's a exaggerated way to describe the character's trait, but it's also a reference to something!

Comment: @gigiistrash Since you are the original poster, if you like my answer please mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: @gigiistrash I second the nomination of this answer (rather than my own answer!) to be accepted by you, since it was the most useful to you and there has been plenty of time for other answers to be posted. It's time to click the check mark!

Answer (score 36):

A **recluse**.

From The Collaborative International Dictionary of English v.0.48 [gcide]:

Recluse \Re*cluse"\ (r[-e]*kl[=u]s"), a. [F. reclus, L.
     reclusus, from recludere, reclusum, to unclose, open, in LL.,
     to shut up. See {Close}.]
     Shut up, sequestered; retired from the world or from public
     notice; solitary; living apart; as, a recluse monk or hermit;
     a recluse life
     [1913 Webster]

Comment: I think recluse actually works a bit better than *hermit*, which was the first thing that I thought of, until I read the description.

Comment: I think a recluse has a reputation sometimes for being insecure. A "proud" recluse seems a bit off. I would go with the "lone wolf" which has some negative connotations for different reasons (i.e., they are unwilling to ask for help even when it is in their best interest).

Comment: I don't think this really matches what OP is looking for. A recluse is someone who is isolated from society specifically because they don't leave their house (thus the etymology from "enclose" or "shut up." OP is looking to describe someone who goes out in the world and does things just like everyone else, except that they do those things alone.

Answer (score 24):

***Maverick*** -- [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/maverick)

> *noun* 2. a lone dissenter, as an intellectual, an artist, or a politician, who takes an independent stand apart from his or her associates.
>
> *adj.* 4. unorthodox, unconventional, nonconformist

Comment: Maverick would probably work here, but even aside from the Sarah Palin connection, it has a very strong connotation of someone who is a cowboy, who *can't* work with others when required to, not just someone who prefers to work alone.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks! And @Cody Gray, that is exactly my character, she cannot work with anyone.

Comment: As @CodyGray says, there is a connotation for being unable to work with others as well as nonconformist. Lone wolf also has the connotation of being unable or unwillingness to work with others, but perhaps more borne out of stubbornness than defiance.

Answer (score 20):

You could call Marina a **hermit**.

[From dictionary.com:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hermit)

**hermit**

noun

1. a person who has withdrawn to a solitary place for a life of religious seclusion.
2. any person living in seclusion; recluse.

(I have omitted several other less relevant senses of the word.)

While Marina's independence does not seem to have a religious component,
it seems to be a deliberate choice based on strong belief,
which the religious connotation of the word *hermit* would
appropriately suggest.

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps Marina can be described as an **Introvert**?

> #### Introvert
>
> 1. A person who is energized by spending time alone. Often found in their homes, libraries, quiet parks that not many people know about, or other secluded places, introverts like to think and be alone.
> 2. A person characterized by concern primarily with his or her own thoughts and feelings

[[UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Introvert) / [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/introvert)]

Contrary to popular belief, not all introverts are shy. Some may have great social lives and love talking to their friends but just need some time to be alone to "recharge" afterwards.

Comment: You most definitely don't have to be shy to be an introvert. I would consider myself an introvert but not shy. I just don't like spending time with most people, especially groups of people. I'm quite capable of being social, I just choose not to.

Comment: That's why I clarified, so nobody would make assumptions.

Comment: Ah, yes, my character is most definitely an introvert, but I was looking for something that focuses more on the individual part.

Comment: @gigiistrash And Introvert, to you, does not provide that alone/individual aspect?

Comment: While your definition of "introvert" is certainly correct, I don't think it fits well in the OP's proposed sentence: *"Marina is a proud **introvert**, she believes that **buddies are for weak people**, and she could very well cope on her own."*  Speaking as a proud introvert myself, I certainly don't think "buddies are for weak people."  I like my alone time, but I can also appreciate the value of teamwork

Comment: The way I read it, the rest of the sentence builds on the "introvert", it doesn't explain it further. If she wanted it to explain it further, I feel like it should be *"Marina is a proud introvert **;** she believes that buddies are for weak people and she could very well cope on her own."* (See the semi-colon instead of comma). That was my intention. I purposely picked a word that didn't include the rest of the sentence's description because of how the sentence was structured.

Answer (score 16):

You should consider *misanthrope*. It does imply the individualistic qualities you're looking for, though it adds a shade of dislike towards others.

> #### Misanthrope
>
> - A person who dislikes humankind and avoids human society.

[Bing]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! :)

Comment: There's not just a "shade" of dislike. If I hear someone's a misanthrope, I'm thinking they go out of their way to harm others. They're probably a sadist.

Comment: @DCShannon Interesting interpretation. I've never considered misanthropism to imply sadism, and I can't recall ever seeing that association be assumed. It's usually more of a cynicism and disgust, but not necessarily active harm. To me it brings to mind the "cranky old man".

Comment: @JasonC If that's the case, then the only times I've heard this used were oddities. I'll look into it a little when I have time.

Answer (score 11):

You may call them a ***lone ranger (or loner)*** too.

M-W:

> **[lone ranger](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lone%20ranger)**
>   *noun*, often capitalized L&R
>
> :  one who acts alone and without consultation or the approval of
>   others; broadly :  loner
>
> something of a lone ranger among anthropologists, she does her
>   research without either a lending hand or an eye toward trendy topics
>
> **[loner](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loner)**
>   *noun*
>   :  one that avoids others; especially :  individualist
>
> that guy in tech support is a loner, and never wants to hang out with
>   the rest of us

Comment: The noun _loner_ has a negative connotation?

Answer (score 7):

You could describe her as a **solitary** individual.

OED:

> b. Keeping apart or aloof from society; avoiding the company
>   of others; living alone.

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/solitary):

> Done or existing alone:
>   ‘I live a pretty solitary life’

I believe it can also be used as a noun, but I'm less familiar with this usage so perhaps it's a little more obscure:

OED:

> b. One who lives by himself in seclusion or retirement;
>   one who avoids, or is deprived of, the society of others.

Oxford Dictionaries:

> A recluse or hermit

Comment: And with an excellent history of usage: "Hard and sharp as flint, from which no steel had ever struck out generous fire; secret, and self-contained, and solitary as an oyster." - Charles Dickens; A Christmas Carol. +1

Answer (score 6):

Here's a few which haven't yet been mentioned:

> **[Iconoclast](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/iconoclast)**—A person who doesn't adhere to tradition
>
> **[Non-conformist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonconformist)**—Someone who doesn't conform to generally accepted patterns of thought or action
>
> **[Anomaly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anomaly)**—Deviation from the common rule
>
> **[Outsider](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/outsider)**—A person who does not belong to a particular group
>
> **[Freethinker](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freethinker)**—A person who thinks freely or independently

Comment: +1 for outsider, but definitions should have citations

Comment: @DCShannon, right you are. Done.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd concur with "anomaly", which just means something different without saying in what way.

Answer (score 4):

**self-reliant**: autonomous person who shies away from relying on other people.

[oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/self-reliant)

> Reliant on one's own powers and resources rather than those of others.
>   ‘a self-reliant little girl’

Answer (score 2):

"Marina is a **free spirit"**

***Free spirit*** -- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/free-spirit)

> (noun) a person who does what they want with enjoyment and pleasure and does not feel limited by the usual rules of social behaviour
>
> *"He has every appearance of the truly free spirit, but he is secretly dependent on that against which he is fighting."*

Must read: [What It Means To Be A Real Free Spirit](http://thoughtcatalog.com/kimberly-yu/2015/02/what-it-means-to-be-a-real-free-spirit/)

> A real free spirit doesn’t mind being alone. They don’t mind sitting at home on a Saturday night and just reading a book. They don’t mind being single. They don’t mind being in a relationship. They don’t mind not having friends to hangout with. They are very mellow about it and doesn’t let their relationships with others define them. In fact, they don’t really let anything define them.

Comment: _Free spirit_ has more connotations of being a bit of a hippie. Free spirits are generally fine being on their own, but there is no inherent sense that they actively _reject_ friendships as signs of weakness. That sounds like a very _non_-free-spirit thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Marina could be called, "antisocial". A person who prefers solitude, tends towards rudeness or other behaviors others find distasteful when in a group.

Has anyone heard the phrase, No man is an island? Nobody can be 100% self sufficient in ALL ways. 
This applies equally to women as it does to men.

Comment: Can you provide support for your answer? What is the definition of anti-social, for those who don't know? What does "No man is an island" have to do with the OP? More information is needed, please.

Comment: I think "unsociable" is better in this context, "anti-social" typically implies behaviors that harm others, whereas "unsociable" just means "disinclined to be social"

Answer (score 2):

**unsociable**

> adjective
>
> not enjoying or making an effort to behave sociably in the
> company of others. "Terry was grumpy and unsociable"
> synonyms: unfriendly, uncongenial, unneighborly, unapproachable,
> introverted, reticent, reserved, withdrawn, aloof, distant, remote,
> detached, unsocial, antisocial, asocial, taciturn, silent, quiet;
> informalstandoffish "we found him to be stiff and unsociable"
> antonyms: friendly not conducive to friendly social relations.
> "watching TV is a fairly unsociable activity"

In your context, you could write,

> Marina is proud to be unsociable

Comment: Want to +1, but that's an awfully large block of uncited text

Answer (score 2):

There are a few musical/public performance multi-word terms that have had their meanings extended figuratively to describe people like Marina and the way might choose to live their lives and conduct their affairs, such as:

[**one-woman/man/person show/band**](https://books.google.com/books?id=9QuEiIMaBt0C&pg=PA322&lpg=PA322&dq=%22one-man+show%22+american+heritage+idioms&source=bl&ots=fHLZtJAQ8d&sig=PD63wRH3Vd9N2aXUsPopp2qKLFo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ1-y1ju_RAhWDbSYKHY7bAXEQ6AEILTAE#v=onepage&q=%22one-man%20show%22%20american%20heritage%20idioms&f=false)=”A person who does or manages just about everything” (from *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms, Second Edition*, via *Google Books*)

and

[**solo act**](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/t/timgunn493188.html)
cf: “Life is not a solo act. It's a huge collaboration, and we all need to assemble around us the people who care about us and support us in times of strife.”
(from *BrainyQuote*, attributed to fashion designer Tim Gunn)

"Marina is a proud (and/or confirmed) **solo act** // **one-woman band/show**, she believes that buddies are for weak people, and she could very well cope on her own,"

For what little it’s worth, [*Urban Dictionary*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/author.php?author=soloist) even has a seemingly relevant definition for a single word:

> **soloist**
>
> A person who likes to be on his own
>      Jay: im going to Appletree
>   college come with me?
>      Ken: nah man im a soloist, im doing this by
>   my self

"Marina is a proud (and/or confirmed) **soloist**, she believes that buddies are for weak people, and she could very well cope on her own,"