# Someone who thinks they can do everything but they can't

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What would you call someone who is extremely independent and thinks that they can do everything on their own, but in reality they are getting swamped and cannot handle the pressure without help. Not a loner, just likes to handle things by themselves without getting anyone else involved.
Is there such a word or phrase?

Comment: Is this someone who can't say no to things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you call a person who is utterly independent and a loner?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/371152/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-is-utterly-independent-and-a-loner) (text enlargement: 'Marina is a proud _____, she believes that buddies are for weak people, and she could very well cope on her own.' [which of course nobody can])

Comment: The suggested question has several answers, but none quite carry the explicit idea of failure which this question includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say that person:

***[Bites off more than they can chew](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bite+off+more+than+can+chew)***

> To try to do more than you are able to do.
>
> *Don't bite off more than you
>   can chew. Let someone else organize the party.*

(Farlex)